# Confusion with services and certificates with an anonymous client

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, certificate, security

I've setup a WCF service that is using transport security over netTcpBinding.  The certificate used for the service's security is signed by a CA we created for development.

Can someone explain how it works that my anonymous client can connect and communicate with the service without having that same CA installed locally?  I'm rather new to certificates and would have assumed that the CA would have to be installed locally for the client to be able to decrypt the data from the service.

The service and client are both on Windows machines, and the client is a Windows Forms .NET 3.5 app.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's two parts to the equation:

- you could have a **server** certificate which the service uses to authenticate itself to the clients (to prove it's really the service it claims to be)
- you could have a **client** certificate which the client needs to prove its identity to the server

Which are you interested in?

Typically, if you have a server/service certificate, the client will either "know" the server's public key (it could be installed in the client's certificate store, e.g. by an installation program or by downloading and installing it), or it will inquire about the server's certificate at the time the proxy gets created and stores the server's public key in the local client config file for later use. This config will then again be installed with the app on the client.

If the client wants to authenticate itself against the service, it will definitely need to have its client certificate installed locally on the client machine's cert store.

I'd recommend checking out the [WCF Security Guidance](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=How%20Tos) - it's a great resource, and they can explain how to do certain scenarios much better than I can!

On a all-Windows environment with everyone in the same domain, this seems like a bit of overkill - why not just use the built-in, Windows-provided credentials? That would be a lot easier, I would think.

Marc

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I should be clear that this is currently working, but we're trying to figure out HOW since we don't see our CA on the client at all.  Maybe ClickOnce is adding it to the config?

We are interested in server certificate only.  The client is deployed via ClickOnce and the user logs in via our application.

Trust me, I wish we could use Windows credentials.  Unfortunately many of our sites/clients aren't on a domain, and each client terminal can house several users throughout the day that are logged on to Windows with a single user.